# CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER display results & file download size

Tags: php, curl

I have a few questions about how CURL delivers content when I make a request.

1. When I make a request to pull a page using CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,d I know I can view the page pulled by just echoing the `curl_exec()` result. My questions is when I echo the result, is the pages content like images downloaded at that time of viewing, or is all the content grabbed once the request is made and held into a buffer till I echo it?
2. How can I see what the total size of downloaded content (html + images + css + js) is from the page. I have tried working with `curl_getinfo()`, but it only shows me the size of the HTML file.
3. I think #2 might answer my questions for #1 in that curl only sees the HTML file till its viewed via echo. If this is the case, is there a curl command that can grab everything?

Answer (score 1):

1. You will get HTML file only
2. You should parse HTML and download all of the needed files and then calculate the total size
3. See #2

Comment: Any suggestions on how to accomplish #2. Thanks.

Comment: I think that you should use `PCRE` functions to search the needed urls. And then - just download in loop with the results.

Comment: For #2, you can also use [SimpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse your HTML for you.